# Laravel 5: upload multiple files and other input

Tags: php, html, laravel

Im having trouble with my form with Laravel 5. When I specify the enctype attribute to 'multipart/form-data' I receive a token mismatch error. If it is removed, the form always fails the validation specified in my controller.

HTML

```
<form class="lajax" action="{{ action('AlbumController@store') }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Album Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">                                                
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="coverFile">Album Cover Image</label>
                        <input  name="cover" type="file" id="coverFile">
                        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="albumFiles">Album Images</label>
                        <input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Album</button>

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //request input verification rules
        $rules=[
            'name'=>'required',
            'cover'=>'required|image',
            'photos'=>'required|array',
            'photos.*'=>'image'
        ];

        //perform validation
        $this->validate($request,$rules);

       // blah blah
    }
```

Specifically, the images seem to be failing.

Errors Reported: cover is not an image, photo.0 is not an image, photo.1 is not and image..... and so forth.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error! It was in my php.ini file. I change post_max_size fom 3M to 1000M. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<form class="lajax" action="{{ action('AlbumController@store') }}" method="POST">
```

To:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('AlbumController@store') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In your controller you can check your input like this:

```
$request->hasFile('file_input_name');
```

Also check Laravel Collective to create forms: https://laravelcollective.com/